# Regular Expression: Strip out data- attributes from HTML elements

Tags: html, regex, custom-data-attribute

I'm struggling with a regular expression.  I'd like to strip out all data- attributes from html elements using regular expression.  For example let's say I have this text:

```
<a href="" data-foo data-foo-bar data-test="foo" data-foo='blah'>
  testing data-foo attributes.
</a>
```

I'd like to remove all data-* if it's inside of an HTML tag, but not from the text.  The result should be:

```
<a href="">
  testing data-foo attributes.
</a>
```

This is what I have, but it inappropriately strips out data-* from text:

```
/(data-.+?=".*?")|(data-.+?='.*?')|(data-[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/g
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1848654

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: @ToniLeigh: JavaScript, but this problem isn't language specific.

Comment: @JohnnyOshika I ask for two reasons, firstly the syntax of application can vary between languages (small point); secondly though, depending on language there may well be a better way to manipulate HTML depending on the languages DOM functions and inbuilt HTML parsing functions - regex manipulation of HTML strings is notoriously difficult

Comment: @ToniLeigh: It looks like regex is a difficult way to solve this, so I've had to resort to string parsing and iterating.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do to delete all `data-*` attributes.

```js
// select all elements. Or just specific ones.
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

// use dataset api to delete all properties.
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    for (var prop in elements[i].dataset) delete elements[i].dataset[prop];
}
```

```html
<a href="" data-foo data-foo-bar data-test="foo" data-foo='blah'>
  testing data-foo attributes.
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you.  That's probably a good workable solution if I had access to the DOM, but I don't.  I'm looking to do some string manipulation.

Comment: Oh, OK. That's a totally different story than, sorry.

Comment: I'm a real noob when it comes to regex, but would this work for you [https://regex101.com/r/mC6wM6/2](https://regex101.com/r/mC6wM6/2) ? I'm not even sure if that is the correct way to do it.

Comment: @JohnnyOshika - if you can run JavaScript on the HTML string then you have access to the DOM

Comment: @ToniLeigh - Not really, if you don't know the environment or the context in which the OP wants to do the string manipulation, you can't just assume that there is a DOM. The DOM is not part of the JavaScript language.

Comment: @DavidDomain: Your regex attempt is pretty good, but there are some scenarios where it doesn't work, such as <a data-foo></a> and <a data-foo="bar"></a>.

Comment: @DavidDomain, true, but it can convert a string into DOM

Comment: its not using regex as asked in question